# Lotus Notes: View selection from picklist

Tags: forms, view, lotus-notes

```
    picklist = w.Pickliststrings (3, 0, server_name, nfs_name, "vwaDoc", "Docs", "Select", 1, "")

    If Not Isarray(picklist) Then Exit Sub

    Set doc_new = db_colector.GetDocumentByUNID (Cstr (picklist (0)))
```

The above view is listing having the first column - categorized some docs. from different 2 forms.

I want after I press the `OK` button from the picklist to be able to get only a doc. from, let say, `formA`.

I was able to manage the following condition:

```
If doc_new.Form(0) = "fmB" Then 'form B => Not
            Msgbox "Bla bla bla, wrong document ", 32, "Atention"
            Goto et

Else
```

But what if the user is selecting the categorized section ( the first column, which has no form ) ?

I tried something like this:

```
If doc_new.Form(0) Is Nothing Then 
            Msgbox "no doc.", 32, "Atentie"
            Goto et
End if
```

I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
If doc_new Is Nothing then
```

which will show that a document has not been selecetd (and a category has)

Comment: Mike, exactly in this moment I have found this solution , also : ) I just wanted to delete the question, but I guess it is wrong to keep it.

Comment: Always good to keep the question with an answer for others future reference. Plus, does my reputation some points scoring!!! Glad you found it and resolved it